# Django Error : ValueError at / Field 'ticket_id' expected a number but got 'NS000001'

Tags: python, django, insert

While Inserting data, I got this error. May be this could be due to change of default primary key. I do not want to enter ticket_id field as I have set default value for that field (default='NS000001')

models.py

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    ticket_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default='NS000001', editable=False)
    server_details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    send_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    license_no = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d/')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticket_id
```

views.py

```
def Index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SaveTicket(request.POST,request.FILES or None) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print(form)
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = SaveTicket()
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

forms.py

```
class SaveTicket(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = ['server_details','send_date','license_no','file']
```

Comment: An `AutoField` is an `IntegerField` with some extra logic, so `default='NS000001` makes no sense.

Comment: I want to start my primary key from 'NS000001', further, 'NS000002', 'NS000003'..and so on..please suggest me for any changes

Comment: What does NS stand for? One option would be to just have the number as the key and add NS when printing it out...

Comment: Note that AutoField will sometimes skip numbers, so if that's a problem in your situation, you have to use something else

Comment: If the NS prefix won't be the same on all tickets, you'll need to make the field a  CharField and allocate it in your code, rather than relying on Django

Comment: @JiříBaum  NS stands for my company code. NS prefix is fixed for all my tickets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## first

you don't need define Autofield yourself.

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    server_details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    send_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    license_no = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

## second

If your Ticket ID is static - you can create a property:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):

    ...  # any staff here

    @property
    def ticket_id(self):
        return f'NS{(self.pk or 0):06d}'
```

## last

after that you can use it everywhere:

```
print(ticket.ticket_id)
>>>'NS2134154'
```

Comment: To get the numbers formatted like "NS000001" the property should probably use `return f'NS{self.pk or 0:06d}'`

Comment: i am agree.  i add it in answer

Comment: @MaximDanilov & @ Jiří Baum ....Thank you so much !! It works fine now. I have two more issues and after that my project will be completed.